# How to add line break in pdf generated using pdfkit.from_string()?

Tags: python, pdf, pdfkit

I try to generate a pdf file from a string using pdfkit. However, in the result all new line characters `\n` are ignored. Thus, I get a pdf with a string printed as a single sentence. For example:

```
import pdfkit
s = "Some text\n"
s += "Ok, let's add something more\n"
s += "And more..."
pdfkit.from_string(s,"file.pdf",{'encoding':'utf-8'})
```

Following code results in a following output (meaning a pdf file with following text):

> Some text Ok, let's add something more And more...

However, this is what I want to achieve:

> Some text
>
> Ok, let's add something more
>
> And more...

Answer (score 0):

you can replace the '\n' with a `moveDown()` operation in javascript so far.

```js
let doc = new PDFDocument({ size: "A4", margin: 50 });
doc.text("Some text")
   .moveDown()
   .text("Ok, let's add something more")
   .moveDown()
   .text("And more...");

doc.end();
const path = "/Users/user1234/Documents/stackoverflow.pdf"
doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(path));
```

For strings which content you don't know, you can write a parser that also executes the moveDown() operation once it sees a linebreak.